# Place API - getting place photo as marker icon

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I follow this guide
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#places_photos
to create place photo as marker icon. This is my map initialization code:

```
var map;

function initMap() {
    // Create a map centered in Pyrmont, Sydney (Australia).
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {lat: -6.920812, lng: 107.604116},
        zoom: 13
      });

      var request = {
        location: map.getCenter(),
        radius: '5000',
        type: ['shopping_mall']
      };

      var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
      service.textSearch(request, callback);
}

// Checks that the PlacesServiceStatus is OK, and adds a marker
// using the place ID and location from the PlacesService.
function callback(results, status) {
  console.log(results);
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        var place = results[i];
        createPhotoMarker(place);
      }
  }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

this is the createPhotoMarker function

```
function createPhotoMarker(place) {
      var photos = place.photos;
      if (!photos) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: place.geometry.location,
            title: place.name
          });
          return;
      }

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: place.geometry.location,
        title: place.name,
        icon: photos[0].getUrl({'maxWidth': 35, 'maxHeight': 35})
      });
}
```

the function will create regular marker if place photo is not available. But for the place with photo available, I get this error : 
**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()** lh3.googleusercontent.com/w35-h35-p/AF1QipOIL6GVVmtqp_cw_hBEQxdILZSa8poMO0HAqFHd=k 
And the map only shows regular marker.
What did I do wrong?

This is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/v90fmrhp/

**==========Update 2017-07-07============**

Thanks for the answers and fixes

It seems the issue solved. My fiddle is working now
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63298126

> Marked as Fixed
>   Good news! We have fixed this issue. Thanks for your patience.
>   
> Happy Mapping!

Comment: FWIW, I'm currently experiencing the exact same issue. May be a temporary problem on Google's end.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like the error you are seeing is caused by some issue on Google's side. It's affecting quite a few other users as well, have a look at their public issue tracker:

> Thanks for reporting this issue. We verified it and we'll keep tracking it.
>   https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63298126

**UPDATE (2017-07-06):**

> A fix for this is going into our release process now and it should be out soon - probably Monday at the latest.
>   https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63298126#comment13

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue and Sulyman suggested a workaround that is working but I don't know for how long when google fixes this.

[Google Places Photos .GetUrl is adding width and height to url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44939403/google-places-photos-geturl-is-adding-width-and-height-to-url)

Here is what we did.

```
if(place.photos != null){
          for(var i = 0; i < place.photos.length; i++){
            //Do a string replace to get the w-h-p out of there.
            var str = place.photos[i].getUrl({"maxWidth": 100, "maxHeight": 100});
            var res = str.replace("w100-h100-p", "p");
            self.pacPhotos.push({
              id : res

            });

          }
        }else {
          console.log("no photo");
        }
      }
```

Comment: I randomly started runnign into this with google places images as well.  Your solution fixed it for me!!!  5 hours ago, man perfect saved my life!

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into this with google places api.  Everything was working fine then randomly it stopped.  It seems likely that it is due to google making changes as they get ready for releasing a better maps api to support vector

@DKinnison saved me with his solution so I just wanted to post my ES6 solution for parsing a received place.  I commented out the other properties I am personally not using in case you need to.

```
const PHOTO_WIDTH = 600;
const PHOTO_HEIGHT = 600;

export function parseGooglePlace(place) {
  if (!place) {
    return;
  }
  const {
    // address_components,
    formatted_address,
    geometry,
    // icon,
    // id,
    // international_phone_number,
    name,
    // rating,
    // reviews,
    // opening_hours,
    photos: _photos = [],
    place_id,
    // reference,
    types = [],
    // url: mapsURL,
    // utc_offset,
    // vicinity,
    website,
  } = place;

  const photos = _photos.map(p =>
    p
      .getUrl({ maxWidth: PHOTO_WIDTH, maxHeight: PHOTO_HEIGHT })
      .replace(`w${PHOTO_WIDTH}-h${PHOTO_HEIGHT}-p`, 'p'),
  );

  return {
    website,
    name,
    photos,
    address: formatted_address,
    placeId: place_id,
    geometry,
    types,
  };
}
```