# Google Places Photos .GetUrl is adding width and height to url

Tags: google-places-api, geturl

I'm trying to get images from google places. All is working for details: reviews, address... but when I try to get photos, I get a 404.

```
if(place.photos != null){
      for(var i = 0; i < place.photos.length; i++){
        var str = place.photos[i].getUrl({"maxWidth": 100, "maxHeight": 100});
        var res = str.replace("w100-h100-p", "p");
        self.pacPhotos.push({
          id : res

        });

      }
    }else {
      console.log("no photo");
    }
  }
```

This will return the list ok but the URL is formatted wrong. it comes out like this.

" https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/w100-h100-p/AF1QipN3xzffYDPCyEIWnvAQGd3RwNs2C14sVlSqrrAh=k "

What I gather it wants is this.
" https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipN3xzffYDPCyEIWnvAQGd3RwNs2C14sVlSqrrAh=k "

The only difference is the "w100-h100-"

*** There is a great work-around here from "Sulyman". I know it's not a long term solution as I'm sure google will fix their results (as discussed here [Place API - getting place photo as marker icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44918164/place-api-getting-place-photo-as-marker-icon) )

For now I've adjusted the code above to reflect Sulymans suggestion. ***

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Place API - getting place photo as marker icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44918164/place-api-getting-place-photo-as-marker-icon)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems like every API Key generates different path
for example you got `w100-h100-p` and i got `w200-p`
and the good news that this section whatever it is...is fixed so you can replace it with another string which is `p`

```
var str = place.photos[0].getUrl();
var res = str.replace(""w100-h100-p", "p");
```

or you can delete the `w100-h100-`

Comment: This worked but the issue appears to be on google end and is being discussed over here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44918164/place-api-getting-place-photo-as-marker-icon 

I really appreciate your help on this! For now I can move forward :)